# setAdapter() of recyclerview causes crash saying circular dependency cannot exist in Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using a simple activity to show recyclerview with some data but when i populate adapter and call setAdapter on it, my app crashes with this error and this happens only in Marshmallow and below apis. It is working fine in Nougat and Oreo.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aamishkhan.tablayoutandbottomnavigationviewsample, PID: 11001
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1724)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:382)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:389)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:8994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1585)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Yes I know what circular references are in relative layout. However i cannot see any circular references in my xml file. It contains only a recyclerview.

My main java class

```
package com.example.aamishkhan.tablayoutandbottomnavigationviewsample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StocksRvAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<StocksBean> stocksIndicesBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        StocksBean stocksBean = new StocksBean("First", "REG", "1.0", "2.0", "3.0",
                "50", "50.0", "60", "abc", "false",
                "100", "110", "0950", "5000", "20",
                "0", "50.0", "80.0", "open", "10000",
                "4000", "12052017", "80");

        stocksIndicesBeanList.add(stocksBean);
    }

    adapter = new StocksRvAdapter(this, stocksIndicesBeanList, "indexes");
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

My custom adapter layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:background="#07223a">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/separatorend"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/separatorend">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/symbolname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/symbolfullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/symbolname"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#bec191"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/netchange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/symbolfullname"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#49d4b5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/netpercrl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#19262f">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/netchangepercent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#49d4b5"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/netchangepercent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainseparator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainrl"
        android:background="#274a60" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainrl"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#19262f"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Hi"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/low"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Low"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ldcp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="LDCP"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lasttradeprice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="LTP"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/volume"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Vol"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#19262f"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totaltrades"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Trades"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d6e8e4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hivalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#9daeaa"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lowvalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ldcpvalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lasttradepricevalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/volumevalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#274a60" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totaltradesvalue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/separatorend"
        android:background="#ebebeb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainrl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainseparator"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imagesrl"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagesrl"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainseparator"
        android:id="@+id/imagesrl"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <!--<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">-->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <!--<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/analytics_sign" />-->

        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter class

```
public class StocksRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StocksRvAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<StocksBean> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<StocksBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
ArrayList<Integer> sectionForPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> positionForSection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> sectionsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
ArrayList<String> sectionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
String searchType = "Scrip";
private String sector = "";
private String market = "";

public StocksRvAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StocksBean> listItems, String searchType) {
    this.context = context;
    this.searchType = searchType;
    //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (listItems != null) {
        this.allItems = listItems;
        this.result = listItems;
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // create a new view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocks_item_rv, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

String netChange;
String netChangePercentage;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (allItems.size() > 0) {

        StocksBean rowItem = allItems.get(position);

        holder.symbolName.setText(rowItem.getSymbolCode());
        holder.symbolFullName.setText(rowItem.getSymbolCode());
        holder.netChangetv.setText(rowItem.getNetChange());
        holder.netChangetvPercentage.setText(rowItem.getNetChangePercent());
        holder.hiValue.setText(rowItem.getHighPrice());
        holder.lowValue.setText(rowItem.getLowPrice());
        holder.ldcpValue.setText(rowItem.getLastDayClosePrice());
        holder.ltpValue.setText(rowItem.getLastTradePrice());
        holder.volumeValue.setText(rowItem.getTotalTradeVolume());
        holder.totalTradesValue.setText(rowItem.getLastTradeVolume());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allItems.size();
}

public String getSector() {
    return sector;
}

public void setSector(String sector) {
    this.sector = sector;
}

public String getMarket() {

    return market;
}

public void setMarket(String market) {
    this.market = market;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView symbolName;
    private TextView symbolFullName;
    private TextView netChangetv;
    private TextView netChangetvPercentage;
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView hiValue;
    private TextView lowValue;
    private TextView ldcpValue;
    private TextView ltpValue;
    private TextView volumeValue;
    private TextView totalTradesValue;
    private ImageView addImage;
    private ImageView detailsImage;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        symbolName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.symbolname);
        symbolFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.symbolfullname);
        netChangetv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.netchange);
        netChangetvPercentage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.netchangepercent);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        hiValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hivalue);
        lowValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lowvalue);
        ldcpValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ldcpvalue);
        ltpValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lasttradepricevalue);
        volumeValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volumevalue);
        totalTradesValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totaltradesvalue);
        addImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        //detailsImage = view.findViewById(R.id.details);
    }
}
}
```

I have been stuck on it for 2 days now and still can't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. This line was the problem in my adapter xml android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainrl"

```
<View
android:layout_width="2dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/separatorend"
android:background="#ebebeb"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainrl"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainseparator"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imagesrl"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagesrl"/>
```

Somehow it was not being detected in Nougat and above API's but on Marshmallow and below it was being detected by the system so making the crash. Removing this line solved the crash.